# Chart.js - Change the data of several donut in mouseover

Tags: javascript, chart.js, mouseover

I need some help. I have to make a page with graphics. I have a large doughnut and other small doughnuts, on mouseover the big donut changes color, but I have to make  when the big donut changes, the small donuts become opaque. 
They should be opaque, except for the small donut that is the same color as the big donut when hovering.

I add photo as an example [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X2tg8.png)

This is my data:

```js
 //Big doughnut data
 var ctx = document.getElementById('canvasDoughnut').getContext('2d');
   var backgroundColors = [
             '#fd3f4a',
             '#484848',
             '#705bc9',
             '#008ee5',
             '#00c9d8',                 
             '#5cc600',
             '#ffd939',
             '#ff8f00'

   ];

   var newColors =  ['#705bc9', '#ebe9e1'];

   var newData = [78,22];

   var varData = [25, 18, 18, 18, 8, 78, 18, 12];

   var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
      type: 'doughnut',        
         data: {
            datasets: [{                  
                backgroundColor: backgroundColors,
                data: varData                                  
            }]
         },
          
         options: {
             cutoutPercentage: 70,
                
             tooltips: {
                 enabled: false
             },

           
             onHover: function(evt, elements) {
                var datasetIndex;
                var dataset;
                      
                  if (elements.length) {
                     var index = elements[0]._index;
                     datasetIndex = elements[0]._datasetIndex;

                     // Reset old state
                     dataset = chart.data.datasets[datasetIndex];
                     dataset.backgroundColor = ['#705bc9', '#ebe9e1'];
                     dataset.value = [78, 22],
                     dataset.data = [78, 22]
                  }                 
                   chart.update();
             }                    
         },
   });
    
// Mini doughnut data    
var ctxMini = document.getElementById('mini-chart-area').getContext('2d');
var chart = new Chart(ctxMini,{
    type: 'doughnut',
       data : {
           datasets: [{
               data: [ 25, 75 ],

               dataPoints: [{  y: 25 },{  y: 75 }],

               backgroundColor: ['#fd3f4a','#ebe9e1'],
           }],
       },
});

var ctxMini2 = document.getElementById('mini-chart-area2').getContext('2d');
var chart = new Chart(ctxMini2,{
    type: 'doughnut',    
        data: {
            datasets: [{
                data: [ 48, 52 ],

                dataPoints: [{  y: 48 },{  y: 52 }],

                backgroundColor: ['#5cc600','#ebe9e1'],
           }],
        }
});

var ctxMini3 = document.getElementById('mini-chart-area3').getContext('2d');
var chart = new Chart(ctxMini3,{
    type: 'doughnut',    
        data: {
            datasets: [{
                data: [ 18, 82 ],

                dataPoints: [{  y: 18 },{  y: 82 }],

                backgroundColor: ['#705bc9','#ebe9e1'],
           }],
        }
});

var ctxMini4 = document.getElementById('mini-chart-area4').getContext('2d');
var chart = new Chart(ctxMini4,{
    type: 'doughnut',    
         data: {
            datasets: [{
                data: [ 12, 88 ],

                dataPoints: [{  y: 12 },{  y: 88 }],

                backgroundColor: ['#ff8f00','#ebe9e1'],
            }],
        }
});

var ctxMini5 = document.getElementById('mini-chart-area5').getContext('2d');
var chart = new Chart(ctxMini5,{
    type: 'doughnut',    
         data: {
            datasets: [{
                data: [ 8, 92 ],

                dataPoints: [{  y: 8 },{  y: 92 }],

                backgroundColor: ['#00c9d8','#ebe9e1'],
            }],
        }
});

var ctxMini6 = document.getElementById('mini-chart-area6').getContext('2d');
var chart = new Chart(ctxMini6,{
    type: 'doughnut',    
         data: {
            datasets: [{
                data: [ 18, 82 ],

                dataPoints: [{  y: 18 },{  y: 82 }],

                backgroundColor: ['#484848','#ebe9e1'],
            }],
        }
});

var ctxMini7 = document.getElementById('mini-chart-area7').getContext('2d');
var chart = new Chart(ctxMini7,{
    type: 'doughnut',    
         data: {
            datasets: [{
                data: [ 18, 82 ],

                dataPoints: [{  y: 18 },{  y: 82 }],

                backgroundColor: ['#ffd939','#ebe9e1'],
            }],
        }
});

var ctxMini8 = document.getElementById('mini-chart-area8').getContext('2d');
var chart = new Chart(ctxMini8,{
    type: 'doughnut',    
        data: {
            datasets: [{
                data: [ 18, 82 ],

                dataPoints: [{  y: 18 },{  y: 82 }],

                backgroundColor: ['#008ee5','#ebe9e1'],
            }],
        }
});
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<canvas id="canvasDoughnut"></canvas>
<canvas id="mini-chart-area"></canvas>
<canvas id="mini-chart-area2"></canvas>
<canvas id="mini-chart-area3"></canvas>
<canvas id="mini-chart-area4"></canvas>
<canvas id="mini-chart-area5"></canvas>
<canvas id="mini-chart-area6"></canvas>
<canvas id="mini-chart-area7"></canvas>
<canvas id="mini-chart-area8"></canvas>
```